# Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

Tags: java, android

Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

How Can i Slove This Proble i have some problem to run code in project i have large code like 4 library and so many jar can any one help

Comment: You have too many methods, exceeding the limit.  There are a number of existing questions here covering your options.

Comment: ye i have too many methed but need use this mathed i have a big project that use this mathed how to slove this problem

Comment: check the projects which you have added to *your* project in the build path.. check if they share common dependencies which will be loaded..

Comment: there is no error in project but when i m runing project then error come also added library in project